# how to fix an error "Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend."

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I am tring to run SAM (segment-anything) demo notebook on my local computer.

segment-anything/notebooks/automatic_mask_generator_example.ipynb [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/blob/6fdee8f2727f4506cfbbe553e23b895e27956588/notebooks/automatic_mask_generator_example.ipynb)

I could run this file on GoogleColab successfully,
but on my local computer, I got an error

> NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build).

The differences are:
[google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k41KT.png)
[jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PkZt.png)

```
#google colab
PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cu118
Torchvision version: 0.15.2+cu118
CUDA is available: True
```

```
#jupyter notebook
PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cu117
Torchvision version: 0.15.2+cpu
CUDA is available: True
```

What I have tried:
`pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`
`pip install torchvision==0.15.0+cu117`
`conda install torchvision==0.15.0+cu117 -c pytorch -c nvidia`
etc.
but it did not work

Thank you in advance.

install torchvision
check cuda available